# python marshmallow schema Json

Tags: python, json, marshmallow

I am trying to validate a JSON file using the schema listed below, I want to return JSON type like below:

```
{
   "status" : 101,
   "questions" :
   [
     {
       "hCode": "A",
       "qId": 402,
       "questionEn": "q1",
       "rowNo": 1
     },
     {
       "hCode": "A",
       "qId": 403,
       "questionEn": "q2",
       "rowNo": 2
     }
   ]
}
```

Here is my code with marshmallow serialization.

```
class QuestionModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'questions'
qId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
hCode = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
rowNo = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
questionEn = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=True)

def __init__(self, qId, hCode, rowNo, questionEn):
    self.qId = qId
    self.hCode = hCode
    self.rowNo = rowNo
    self.questionEn = questionEn

def __repr__(self):
    return f"questions(qId = {self.qId}, hCode = {self.hCode}, rowNo = {self.rowNo}, " \
           f"questionEn = {self.questionEn}) "


class QuestionModelSchema(ma.Schema):
   class Meta:
       fields = ("qId", "hCode", "rowNo", "questionEn")


question_schema = QuestionModelSchema()
questions_schema = QuestionModelSchema(many=True)


@app.route('/qlist')
def get_questions():
   Questions = QuestionModel.query.all()
   return questions_schema.jsonify(Questions)
```

How should I change my code to validate the JSON file as I mentioned?

Comment: What exactly do you need to know? What have you tried?

Comment: A year late, but here's a medium article that explains how to validate JSON using Marshmallow: https://medium.com/automation-with-donald/validate-json-data-with-marshmallow-bc0200105e0d